# Disable CSS3 animations on incompatible browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fade-in animation on the main container on page load.
It works fine with all browsers expect IE(9).

Is there a way to detect if the user is using a browser incompatible with CSS3 animations and so disable them, so they can view the page?

### HTML

---

```
<body>

    <span id="splash-title">
    <img src="kuntosali/images/fc_yrityskeskus.png" class="pure-img" id="splash-logo" alt="logo" />
    <img src="kuntosali/images/loading.gif" id="loading" alt="loading" />
    </span>

<div class="splash-container">
    <div class="splash">
        <span class="splash-head"></span>
        <p class="splash-subhead">
            <span>FoxCenter</span> on kuntosali ja yrityskeskus.<br>
            Kumpaa etsit?
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="yrityskeskus/" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Yrityskeskus</a>
            <a href="kuntosali/" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Kuntosali
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

### CSS

---

```
.splash {
    /* absolute center .splash within .splash-container */
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation: fade-in 2s forwards 4s;
        -moz-animation: fade-in 2s forwards 4s;
        -o-animation: fade-in 2s forwards 4s;
    animation: fade-in 2s forwards 4s;
}
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Comment: You're missing your CSS in the question.

Comment: I guess you are using `opacity:0` from the begining ... So you need to set opacity:1 if the browser is IE9 or lower Check this http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon This allows me to add HTML classes, which I can modify in CSS, but can it change CSS directly, i.e disable animations?

Comment: @Claudio you can't *disable* animation since if they are not supported, it will be disabled. But you can set the opacity : `.no-cssanimations .splash {opacity:1;}`. It will override your `opacity : 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @Karl-AndréGagnon, using modernizr might be the cleanest way to go. It will then add a `no-cssanimations` class to the `<html>` tag when a browser cannot use CSS3 animations.

You can then use it to add "non-CSS3-animation support CSS or javascript":

- in CSS you will do `.no-cssanimations .splash { /* ...do something */ }`
- in javascript you can do :

`if( Modernizr.cssanimations ){ /* ...do something */ }`

`if( $(".no-cssanimations").length ){ /* ...do something */ }`

Resources

- http://modernizr.com/
- Modernizr development version: http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js
- Modernizr custom builds (for prod): http://modernizr.com/download/

Comment: No need of Modernizr, the property can be checked.

Comment: very interesting thx. any further documentation regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) which is a feature detection library.

If you go to the download page, choose features you want to detect and then add the script to your site.

This will give you access to the Modernizr object in javascript and also add classes to the HTML tag (if that option is selected).

**In CSS:**

```
.cssanimations .splash {
    // Styles for when CSS animations work
}
```

**Or in Javascript:**

```
if( Modernizr.cssanimations ){
    // Javascript if CSS animations work
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: No need of Modernizr, the property can be checked.

Answer (score 0):

If CSS 3 is not supported, animation is ignored and so already disabled.

For a proper detect of animation property in JS, no need:

```
if(typeof(document.body.style.animation) === 'undefined' && typeof(document.body.style.MozAnimation) === 'undefined' && typeof(document.body.style.WebkitAnimation) === 'undefined' && typeof(document.body.style.OAnimation) === 'undefined') {
    // not supported
}
```

You can maybe load jquery, jquery lite or zepto for old browser and do this:

```
if(typeof(document.body.style.animation) === 'undefined' && typeof(document.body.style.MozAnimation) === 'undefined' && typeof(document.body.style.WebkitAnimation) === 'undefined' && typeof(document.body.style.OAnimation) === 'undefined') {
    $('.splash').fadeIn();
}
```

PS: this trick: `bottom: 0; right: 0;` will probably fail on some browsers.

Comment: Could you update your answer with a bit more code, as I'm no genius in JS?

Comment: It's exactly when the animation is unsupported that his opacity will never go to 1, that's his problem ;) Also, FYI, I agree that `bottom : 0;` is not needed, but the `right : 0;` allow him to center his element with `margin : auto;`.

Comment: Actually, `bottom : 0;` is really important since it center vertically as well! (Just learned that)

Comment: Updated, I propose to make your animation with jquery on old browsers. It could be done with pure JS but you will need a few more lines of code. The advantages: everyones will see the animation, and moderns browser will not need to load more scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be completely antiquated here, but here's how I'd do it if I didn't want to use Modernizr.

There are probably a ton of different ways to do this but...

If I were trying to target a specific version of IE (regardless of CSS3), I would just use IE conditional comments.

For example:

Style the fade-in div with display:none; in the linked conditional commented CSS Stylesheet (ie.css or whatever you wish to name it).

That fade-in div would appear in all browsers except the specific IE browsers that you targeted with the conditional comments just by using a tiny bit of CSS. Simple solution and very lightweight.

See more about conditional comments here: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Also, if you wanted to know more about what CSS3 can be used on specific browsers check out http://caniuse.com/

It clearly defines what you can and cannot use for specific browsers (not just IE).